# Golang code to get all the pod details on my setup

Tags: go

I have a setup where k8s is running. When i run the "curl http://< host-ip>/api/v1/pods" i get all the pod details running on my setup. I need to do something similar using the k8s client instead, using the token/certificate authentication.

I did see some code which is similar "[How can I create a simple client app with the Kubernetes Go library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554893/how-can-i-create-a-simple-client-app-with-the-kubernetes-go-library)" but this is not helping me much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your client using

```
rest, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", "kube-config-file")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Failed to load KubeConfig", err)
}


client := clientset.NewForConfigOrDie(rest)

pods, err := client.Core().Pods("").List(api.ListOptions{})
```

if you running this inside the k8s cluster you can do it by

```
rest, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", "")
```

Comment: what is c in (c.RESTConfig)

Comment: even though i added a config which is c here, My code is not able to resolve "Pods("")" in the line pods, err := client.Core().Pods("") Any idea why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554893/how-can-i-create-a-simple-client-app-with-the-kubernetes-go-library Answer given by "Rush", Answer Number 3.

Comment: Similarly in your answer in the line pods, err := client.Core().Pods("").List(api.ListOptions{})
 the Pods("") is not being resolved. Also Note that i have pulled the client code from https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go

Comment: can you be more explicit about the `clientcmd` like where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

It's well know that the official Go client for k8s is a little messy.
I recommend you take a look to this library looks much better:
https://amdatu.org/infra/goclient/gettingstarted/

godocs:
https://godoc.org/bitbucket.org/amdatulabs/amdatu-kubernetes-go/client