# List kubernetes resources by clinet-go, How can I get the kind and apiversion?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, client-go

When I get the kubernetes resources from api with client-go, but I can't found the apiversion and kind in the response, the apiversion and kind is empty. How can I get the apiversion and kind of the resource?

below is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "log"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "fmt"
)

var clientset *kubernetes.Clientset

func main()  {
    k8sconfig := flag.String("k8sconfig","./k8sconfig","kubernetes config file path")
    flag.Parse()
    config , err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("",*k8sconfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    clientset , err = kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("connect k8s success")
    }
    pods,err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
    }
    for _, pod := range pods.Items{
        fmt.Println("apiversion: ", pod.APIVersion, "kind: ", pod.Kind)
    }   
}

The output:
apiversion:   kind:  
apiversion:   kind:  
apiversion:   kind:  
apiversion:   kind:  
apiversion:   kind:  
apiversion:   kind:  
apiversion:   kind:  
apiversion:   kind:
......
......
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are getting the list of pods using the `List()` API so it is not a pod as you expect and doesn't have a `Kind` field.

You need to iterate over the list of pods to access individual pods:

```
for _, pod := range pods.Items {
    fmt.Printf("%s %s\n", pod.GetName(), pod.GetCreationTimestamp())
}
```

The `Kind` field is present as part of [Pod's](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api/core/v1#Pod) [`Metadata`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#TypeMeta) and can be accessed using `pod.ObjectMeta.Kind`.

Comment: further you can use the `Get` API to directly get a specific pod, some examples are explained in [create-a-simple-client-app-with-the-kubernetes-go-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554893/how-can-i-create-a-simple-client-app-with-the-kubernetes-go-library)

Comment: I tried the pod.TypeMeta.Kind and pod.Kind, they are all empty

Comment: what does it print when you print the complete `pod` object? also, please try with `pod.ObjectMeta.Kind` instead of `pod.TypeMeta.Kind`.

Comment: also, have a look at Kamol's answer if you don't see the required field in the pod output.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the `APIVersion` and `Kind` because it was ignored from the code.

If you take a look at the API server JSON [response](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/rest/request.go#L1009), it will be something like below:

```
{
   "kind":"PodList",
   "apiVersion":"v1",
   "metadata":{
      "resourceVersion":"2397"
   },
   "items":[
      {
... ... ...
```

So the response does contain the `APIVersion` and `Kind`. But when the response is decoded to k8s object, [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/rest/request.go#L1309)

```
out, _, err := r.decoder.Decode(r.body, nil, obj)
```

Here you can see that the second output parameter is ignored, which is `schema.GroupVersionKind`.

```golang
func (c *Something) Decode([]byte, *schema.GroupVersionKind, runtime.Object) (runtime.Object, *schema.GroupVersionKind, error) {
    
}
```

**N.B.:** When you are making an API call using the client-go (unless dynamic client), you already know the APIVersion (ie. `CoreV1()` ) and the Kind ( ie. `List()`).